# To check and PUSH the new object to table component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

I have 2 components called `list` & `display`. The `list` component will display customers in the `dropdown`, From the `dropdown(dropdown with multiselect)` I will `PUSH` the selected customers to `table(material component)` present in the `display` component like this:

[image]

Now i have another `form` in `display` component itself in order to generate a new `customer`.From this form i will generate a new customer and i will `PUSH` this new customer to `table` like this:

[image]

And i will update the generated customer in `list` component also like this:

[image]

But the issue is When i try to **PUSH** the same customer(Ex Customer 4) from the **list** component,It should not add the duplicate, but it is adding:

[image]

**Note:**

- Since i can't a generate **ID** for the new customer in the **stackblitz DEMO**, I am just hard coding the **ID** for the new customer(Customer 4)
- And in the **list** also i am just added the new customer as **Customer 4**

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-corvkp?file=src/app/list/list.component.html)**

Comment: Your stackblitz demo dosent work, as you have described

Comment: He means that your stackblitz is broken. In the `list.component.html` the button has two `(click)` events attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check your array for occurrences.

I've updated your [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-lv3cyj) example to work for your requirements. I'd advice you not to store your customers inside CustomerIds object, it'll make it a bit easier.

And just blocking the user from adding is also not the best option, add something to notify the user of the error.